# Starting the kernel in spyder when using offline

Tags: python, spyder

I have users on a Domain Computer using MS folder re-direction. Users take the laptop home to use in standalone mode, when starting Spyder it attempts to "Connect to Kernel" then fails with the following message:

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\main_widget.py", line 2136, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle,
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 30, in wrapped
raise e
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 27, in wrapped
return loop.run_until_complete(future)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 90, in run_until_complete
return f.result()
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
raise self._exception.with_traceback(self._exception_tb)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 232, in __step
result = coro.send(None)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 83, in wrapper
raise e
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 75, in wrapper
out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 385, in _async_start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = await ensure_async(self.pre_start_kernel(**kw))
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 30, in wrapped
raise e
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 27, in wrapped
return loop.run_until_complete(future)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 90, in run_until_complete
return f.result()
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
raise self._exception.with_traceback(self._exception_tb)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 232, in __step
result = coro.send(None)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 351, in _async_pre_start_kernel
kw = await self.provisioner.pre_launch(**kw)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 190, in pre_launch
km.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 503, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 164, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 983, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\fknippa\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 536, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(fname, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
pywintypes.error: (50, 'GetFileSecurity', 'The request is not supported.')
```

Have tried several uninstalls and clean re-installs of Spyder.  Same result.  Cannot seem to figure out what the list line about "win32_restrict_file_to_user" is trying to tell me....any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.